# SQL statement to get the MIN() from the AVG() returned from second query

Tags: sql, sql-server, average, min

I got a question regarding subquery in SQL statement. What I am trying to do is to find a minimum time with the average column result returned from another query.

```
SELECT userID
FROM myTable
WHERE time = MIN(...)

SELECT userID, AVG(date_time)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY userID
```

The second query will return me the average between two times and group by a third party.

Then my first query need to find the minimum average time return from my second query. How can I combine both of the queries together?

The sample data for my second query is like:

```
user1  20
user2  45
user3  10
```

Then for my first query, I need to get the user with minimum average:

```
user3  10
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify what you want to do.

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag since you said you are using SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want one row with the minimum average time, then you can do:

```
SELECT TOP 1 userID
FROM myTable
GROUP BY userID
ORDER BY AVG(date_time) ASC;
```

If you want multiple rows then use `TOP WITH TIES`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES userID
FROM myTable
GROUP BY userID
ORDER BY AVG(date_time) ASC;
```

Comment: I am using MSSQL and it is throwing me error message at the LIMIT

Comment: Alright I figured out to use TOP 1. By the way, what you mean by multiple rows? becuase I thought MIN will just pick the minimum one?

Comment: @2dollar20cents . . . The question was originally tagged "mysql".  I fixed the answer for SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 userID
FROM myTable
GROUP BY userID
ORDER BY AVG(date_time) ASC
```